# Windows 8 won't stop recognizing a "Local area network" automatically

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection

And for some reason, this always ruins my Wi-Fi connection, than I have to go to "Network and Sharing center" and disable this new local area network for my Internet to work again. How do I prevent Windows from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you still want to connect to the network, but you wish to use a wireless connection at the same time.

Try this:

1. From the Start menu, select either **Control Panel**, or **Settings** and then **Control Panel**.
2. Double-click **Network Connections**, and then **Local Area Connection**. In the **Local Area Connection Status** dialog box that appears, click **Properties**.
3. Click to highlight **Internet Protocol Version 4 [TCP/IP]** , and then click the **Properties** button.
4. Select the radio button for **Use the following IP Address**, and enter the IP address of your computer. [see instruction below if you aren't sure]
5. Enter the correct code for the "**Subnet Mask**" field.
6. Enter the correct information for the "**Default Gateway**" field
7. Enter the correct information in the "**Preferred DNS Server**" field and the "**Alternate DNS Server**" field.
8. "**OK**" your way out of the properties.

If you now open the Local Area Connection (the same one from step 2) you should be able to see that under **Connection**, **IPv4 Connectivity** it says 'No Internet Access'.
That means you have succeeded

*To find the codes for steps 4-7*

1. go to start menu,
2. search for **Run**
3. type **cmd**
4. In the new window type **ipconfig /all** and press enter
5. scroll down to the section that reads **Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:**
6. use the codes from that section

Hope this helps.